# LC3 how do I print user input to screen?

Tags: lc3

This is what I have so far:

```
.orig x3000

Lea r0, EnterString             
puts                    
LOOP                    
getc                    

add r1, r0, -10         ;subtract 10 to identified if enter is pressed
brz OUTSIDE             ;if yes, go out of the loop

out                 
brnzp LOOP              

OUTSIDE                 
Lea r1, InputString
puts

Lea r0, EnterString
out
Halt                    

EnterString .stringz "Please enter a string: "
InputString .stringz "\nThe text you have typed is: "

.end
```

I am trying to have user input of upto 99 characters and then print it, but after when i try and print whats been inputted it just prints some weird boxes after the InputString "\nThe text you have typed is: " gets printed.

I think its got something to do with me perhaps accidentally cleaing my EnterString? r0?

Am I close to having it sorting?

I wanted to put a screenshot but I can't because my ranks too low.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general approach isn't correct.  Here's what you have right now:

```
Print out welcome string
Get character
If character is a newline, exit loop, otherwise get another character
Print out "your string is"
Output (incorrectly) welcome string again.
```

All `PUTS` does is to take the effective address stored in r0 and print each character in it, one at a time, until it reaches a '\0' character.  All `GETC` does is to get a single character and store it into r0.  It does not create a stack or a string and it cannot store multiple characters.

In order to store a string from the console, you need to define a place to put it and physically put it there.  You'll need to create a `BLKW` with the number of characters that you want to store (plus room for a null character), then you'll need to:

1. load the address of this `BLKW` into a register
2. move the character from r0 into this address (hint: use `STR`)
3. increment the address so that you're still pointing at an empty position

In order to print it out again, load the effective address of your memory space and call `PUTS`, as you did with the welcome string.

Comment: Thank you for this